# Haproxy logs not getting created in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: logging, ubuntu-16.04, haproxy

With same configuration haproxy logs were logged in /var/log/haproxy.log in ubuntu 14.04, but when moved to ubuntu 16.04 it is failing. I checked different things mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/738501/how-to-fix-simple-haproxy-logging/738508 or https://serverfault.com/questions/488967/haproxy-not-logging.

Nothing seems to work. 
Not able to find the fix whether it is due to systemd changes made in ubuntu 16.04.

haproxy.cfg has :

```
global
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    log /dev/log  local0
    log /dev/log  local1 notice

defaults
    log global
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf :

```
# Create an additional socket in haproxy's chroot in order to allow logging via
# /dev/log to chroot'ed HAProxy processes
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log
&~
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with what I suspect is the same issue. I was expecting to find HTTP access logs in /var/log/haproxy.log. Here is how I fixed my issue and what I discovered.

**Frontend logging**

To log HTTP requests I have the following config:

```
default
  mode http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull

frontend www-http
  bind *:80
  log /dev/log local0
```

The log directive needs to be set on the frontend to get HTTP access logs.

The [dontlognull](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.3.1) option is useful for filtering out TCP probes.

**Global logging**

The log directive under the global config heading is for system errors, start/stop, etc.. ([more info](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8))